# Change in Connection on a complex Line bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, connections

Let's say $M$ is a compact Kähler manifold and $L$ is a complex line bundle on $M$. Now let's say $A$ be a connection or equivalently a hermitian metric on $L$. Hence one can have the operators
$\bar\partial_A,\partial_A$ on forms $\Omega(M,L).$ Now say we add a $\theta\in\Omega^{0,1}(M,i\mathbb{R})$ to the connection $A$. Now what would happen to the operators $\bar\partial_{A+\theta},\partial_{A+\theta},\bar\partial_{A+\theta}^*,\partial_{A+\theta}^*$ in terms of $A$ and $\theta$?

I think $\bar\partial_{A+\theta}$ should be equal to $\bar\partial_A+\theta\wedge ()$ but I am not sure.

Comment: A metrics gives rise to a connection (the Chern connection), but I don't believe you can go in the other direction, and thus it is unclear whether the operators $\bar\partial^*_{A+\theta}$ and $\partial^*_{A+\theta}$ have any meaning. In addition, by adding a non-zero $(0,1)$-form, you can never end up with a Chern connection, since the connection matrix in a holomorphic frame should be $(1,0)$.

Comment: @RichardL I agree but the line bundle is not necessarily holomorphic here and hence Chern connection doesn't make sense. What I mean with a connection $A$ on $L$, we have the operator $\nabla_A$ on forms. Now we have the operators $\partial$ and $\bar\partial$ on $\Omega(M,\mathbb{C})$. $\partial_A$ is obtained by coupling $\partial$ with the covariant derivative $\nabla_A$ on $L$ giving us an operator on $\Omega(M;L)$.

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand what you mean by $\bar\partial^*_{A+\theta}$ and $\partial^*_{A+\theta}$ in this setting.

Comment: @RichardL I mean the dual operators of $\bar\partial_{A+\theta}$ and $\partial_{A+\theta}$. That should make sense right?

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstand you, but don't you simply have $\partial_{A+\theta}=\partial_A$, $\bar{\partial}_{A+\theta}=\bar\partial_{A}+\theta$, $\partial_{A+\theta}^*=\partial_A^*$ and $\bar{\partial}_{A+\theta}^* = \bar\partial_A^*-\theta$, basically by definition of the involved operators?

Comment: I am not exactly sure if $\bar\partial^*_{A+\theta}$ is that simple.

Comment: If you have doubts about this, then I would suggest that you write down precisely how you define all the operators and in view of these definitions verify whether the formulas above hold.